# Is hp 2920-24G compatible with CHEF setup?

Tags: chef-infra, switching

I am using HP 2920-24G switch. In that,I am trying to build the setup for CHEF Client. But it shows error while bootstrapping. Is that HP switch supports CHEF or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chef is not incompatible with any specific kind of networking hardware.  The fact you are using a particular kind of HP switch is highly unlikely to be the cause of your problems.

However, if your network is not configured properly (for your purposes) then it could prevent Chef from talking to other machines that it needs to in order to bootstrap.

You probably need to talk to your local network administrator about this.  It may be that your network or your computer is not set up correctly ... or that there is a firewall interfering with the Chef bootstrapping.

---

**UPDATE** - I misinterpreted the question as you wanting to install / use Chef on a machine connected to the net via an HP switch.

Turns out that you actually wanted to use Chef to *configure* the switch.

That *might* be *theoretically* possible if the switches OS was one of the platforms that Chef supports.  But apparently it isn't.  (Here are the [platform families](http://docs.getchef.com/dsl_recipe_method_platform_family.html) that Chef supports.)

And even if it was theoretically possible, I think that installing Chef and letting it loose on the switch configs would be a really bad idea.  As in *"invalidates the warranty and might turn the switch into an expensive brick"* kind of bad idea.

Comment: I am able to communicate between chef server and workstation. Additionally I am also able to bootstrap a computer as a node.

Comment: So what is the failure are getting?

Comment: HP-2920-24G doesn't support chef because this particular switch is not compatible with Linux and ruby environment.

Comment: Oh I get it.  You are trying to use Chef to *configure* an network switch.  That won't work.  The switch operating system isn't Linux or Windows.

Comment: I wanted to use my network switch as a node for the chef, so that I can able to add or remove the flows from it. Is chef works only in Linux or Windows O.S?

Comment: Basically yes.  Here is the complete list of supported "families" of operating systems: http://docs.getchef.com/dsl_recipe_method_platform_family.html